# Android | disable multi window touchwiz samsung programmatically

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, multi-window, samsung-touchwiz

I actually develop a launcher application and I need to disable the long pressure of the multi task button from Samsung touch-wiz

[image]

After searching some tips, I find this apps who can disable this functionality https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nerd.multiwindowtoggle&hl=fr

However I can't install this app on the one hundred tablet of my compagny so I need to know if anyone knows how this guy has done for this app ?

I already look at the Samsung SDK Multi-Window and tried to disable it with this meta tag but none of these are working

```
<meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.sdk.multiwindow.enable" android:value="false" />
<meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.sdk.multiwindow.multiinstance.enable"
    android:value="false" />
<meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.sdk.multiwindow.penwindow.enable"
    android:value="false" />
```

Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some re-search and some reverse engineering, you can disable it with this code :

```
Settings.System.putInt(getActivity().getContentResolver(), "multi_window_enabled", 0);
```

Comment: I didn't try but i think it's ok, you can try with the app and if it's working the code will work -> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nerd.multiwindowtoggle&hl=fr

Comment: I confirm, it works. But where did you find "multi_window_enable"? Even on android documentation I didn't found it

Comment: I've do some reverse engineering on this APK https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nerd.multiwindowtoggle&hl=fr and i've saw they use this !